# Assigning an instance to an instance of upper class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, instance

Why do we assign an instance to an instance of upper class? What are the reasons to do it?
For ex. why we use this code below?

```
List lst = new LinkedList();
```

It seems List is upper class of LinkedList. Why do we need to use upper class' instance instead of inherited class', LinkedList's, instance.

Also, I've another question.

I've seen some code which assign a class' instance to its interface. Why do we need that example below? I know, since we can't generate instance of an interface, it allows us to use an instance of an interface. But, what's the point of using an instance of an interface?

```
Apple a = new Apple();
IFruit b = (IFruit) a; (IFruit is the interface of Apple)
```

I hope, i've made myself clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit on naming: What you're calling an "upper class" is called a "superclass". In the specific case `List` is an interface and not a class, by the way. Also `lst` is not a "`List` instance" it's a "variable of type `List`".

Comment: Or a "reference of type List". But certainly not an instance. You've got only one instance in the first example, and that's an instance of LinkedList type. The reference variable is pointing to that instance or referencing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Program to interface (abstract).

Later, if you want to LinkedList instead of ArrayList, you just need to change one line code:

```
List lst = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Ah, so you say, with casting i can go between subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

```
List lst = new LinkedList();
```

here `List` is an interface and `LinkedList` is implementation of it.

its not the case of super class subclass here.

`List` declares certain methods that its implementor is forced to implement. 
it will give you advantage of `encapsulation`.

Answer (score 2):

The point of using an interface (what you called an upper class) to abstract away some of the details in your code. You can then write more general code that handles the your data that is of type interface.

With the fruit example, if you have several different types of fruit, then you can write a generic method that accepts IFruit and passes in any type of fruit and know that it will be handled correctly. If you didn't have the interface, then you'd have to write a method for each type of fruit you needed to handle.

Answer (score 1):

This is 'programming to an interface', which allows you to exchange implementation without affecting the rest of code. This way you are following [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which is one of five [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles (one of my best 'OOP principles set' so far), which I would strongly recommend to get familiar with.